# How to enforce JPA to use composite primary key index order

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

table Name : Transfer

Columns : IDENTIFIER,KEY,TRANSFER_NUMBER,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME

Transfer's table composite primary keys are : IDENTIFIER,KEY,TRANSFER_NUMBER

Transfer's table Index INDEX1 definition : IDENTIFIER ASC, KEY ASC, TRANSFER_NUMBER ASC

Transfer pojo

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSFER", indexes = { @Index(name = "INDEX1", columnList = "identifier,key,transferNbr") })
@Getter
@Setter
@DynamicUpdate
public class Transfer implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private TransferPk id;
    
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;
```

TransferPk pojo

```
        @EqualsAndHashCode
        @Getter
        @Setter
        @Embeddable
        public class TransferPk implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Column(name = "IDENTIFIER")
        private String identifier;
        @Column(name = "KEY")
        private int key;
        @Column(name = "TRANSFER_NUMBER")
        private String transferNbr;
```

Code to retrieve Transfer

```
    TransferPk id = new TransferPk();
    id.setIdentifier("123");
    id.setKey(456);
    id.setTransferNbr("789");
    // This JPA query also uses the reverse Transfer of index
    Optional<Transfer> Transfer = TransferRepo.findById(id);
```

I'm able to get data from DB without any issues and HQL is

```
    select <all fileds> from TRANSFER transfer0_ where transfer0_.TRANSFER_NUMBER=? and transfer0_.KEY=? and transfer0_.IDENTIFIER=?
```

Though we used indexes annotation, still JPA is not using the index defined in Transfer table (INDEX1) and hence retrival takes more time.

How to enforce JPA to use index order. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "index order" but you are using JPA attribute names in the `@Index` annotation which is wrong. Use column names like `@Index(name = "INDEX1", columnList = "identifier,key,transfer_number")`

Comment: Thanks Christian. I have tried with attribute name and below is the error.            `Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create index (identifier, key, transferNbr) on table TRANSFER: database column 'identifier', 'key', 'transferNbr' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)`

Comment: I told you to use column names :D using attribute names is wrong

Comment: Opps. Ok. Tried column name and above is the result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1st of all the way you are creating index is wrong. column List will have  always table column name rather than field name.

In your case it would be:---

```
@Table(name = "TRANSFER", indexes = { @Index(name = "INDEX1", columnList = "IDENTIFIER,KEY,TRANSFER_NUMBER ASC") })
```

**"DESC/ASC"** is used for Index order.

Hope , It should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks privranjan. Tried both ASC and DESC but still correct index order is not picked

Executed HQL
`select <all fileds> from TRANSFER transfer0_ where transfer0_.TRANSFER_NUMBER=? and transfer0_.KEY=? and transfer0_.IDENTIFIER=?`

Expected HQL shoiuld be
`select <all fileds> from TRANSFER transfer0_ where transfer0_.IDENTIFIER=? and transfer0_.KEY=? and transfer0_.TRANSFER_NUMBER=?`

Comment: we have appr 1B data in table and index order in DB2 is `IDENTIFIER,KEY,TRANSFER_NUMBER`. But JPA used order as `TRANSFER_NUMBER,IDENTIFIER,KEY`. SO we are ending up with performance issue. To avoid, I'm trying to force JPA to use same oreder which is defined in DB2

Comment: Which hibernate version are you using?

Comment: Check with hibernate 4.3.8 or 5.2.13. it will not work with 5.2.10 version

Comment: My version is 5.3.7

Comment: hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.4.Final.jar
hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar
hibernate-ehcache-5.3.7.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-5.3.7.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.jar

Comment: Can you check with any of the above?